# *ngFor value bind with ngModel

Tags: angular

Here i am trying to *ngFor value bind with ngModel, but when i send the data its not binding.it showing empty object in network, below i am sharing my code.if have some query please ask in comments.Thank you

This is my addtokens.html file

```
    <div class="card-block" style="margin-left:9%" *ngFor="let data of addtokens">
                      <form role="form">
                          <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-xs-12">
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                      <label>FIRST NAME</label>
                                      <div class="input-group">
                                          <input type="tel" style="margin-right:-70%" [(ngModel)]="data.firstname" class="form-control" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" placeholder="Enter First Name" />
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>


                          <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-xs-12">
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                      <label>LAST NAME</label>
                                      <div class="input-group">
                                          <input type="tel" style="margin-right:-70%" [(ngModel)]="data.lastname" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Last Name"/>
                                          <!-- <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-credit-card"></span></span> -->
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>



                          <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-xs-12">
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                      <label>ADDRESS</label>
                                      <div class="input-group">
                                          <input type="tel" style="margin-right:-70%" [(ngModel)]="data.address" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" class="form-control" placeholder="Valid Address" />
                                          <!-- <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-credit-card"></span></span> -->
                                      </div>
                                  </div>



 <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-xs-12">
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <label>CITY</label>
                              <div class="input-group">
                                  <input type="tel"  style="margin-right:-70%" [(ngModel)]="tokens.city" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" class="form-control" placeholder="City" />
                                  <!-- <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-credit-card"></span></span> -->
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>


                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-xs-12">
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <label>ZIPCODE</label>
                              <div class="input-group">
                                  <input type="tel" style="margin-right:-70%" [(ngModel)]="tokens.zipcode" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" class="form-control" placeholder="Zipcode" />
                                  <!-- <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-credit-card"></span></span> -->
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>


                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-xs-12">
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <label>EMAIL</label>
                              <div class="input-group">
                                  <input type="tel" style="margin-right:-70%" [(ngModel)]="data.email" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" />
                                  <!-- <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-credit-card"></span></span> -->
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>



                  <div class="card-footer">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-xs-12">
                              <button class="btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-block" (click)="Addtokens()">Process payment</button>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
```

Here my addtokens.component.ts file

```
    public addtokendata:any[];
  public addtokens:any=[];

  tokens: Addtokens = new Addtokens();


  constructor(private batchservice:BatchService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
// this.Addtokens();
this.autoaddtoken();
  }
private Addtokens()
  {
    this.batchservice.addtoken(this.tokens).subscribe((resp)=>
  {

  })
  }
  public autoaddtoken()
  {
    this.batchservice.autoaddtoken().subscribe((resp)=>
  {
    this.addtokens=resp;
  })
  }
```

Here my addtokens.model.ts file

```
export class Addtokens

    {

         "firstname":string;
         "lastname":string;
        "address":string;
        "city":string;
        "zipcode":string;
         "email":string;
        "cardno":string;
        "cvv":string;
        "tokens":string;
    }
```

Comment: Seems you need to bind to tokens not addtokens

Comment: Do you have any error message? Can you console log your this.addtokens ?

Comment: some field are autofields.thta's why i am using.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using a wrong aproach for this and the syntax is incorrect. In this case you are trying to bind to the last 'data' iteration from the *ngFor. Maybe try going with Reactive or template forms, since its an array i would go with Reactive forms. Angular has excellent documentation for that. If you get stuck hit me up :)

Comment: i assume the variable you are trying to send is called data aswell?

Comment: So how to bind *ngFor value using *ngModel.

Comment: you need to expose the index
*ngFor="let data of addtokens; let i = index;"
bind to and then bind like [(ngModel)] = "addtokens[i].firstName", 
But this aproach is bad, you need forms. This approch will be binding to addtokens since ngModel is binding to the variable being itterated.